# recaptcha doesn't show up with dreamweaver

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver, captcha, recaptcha

I've got a little problem here with reCAPTCHA integration into a dreamweaver project.

I can't see the widget at all, and don't understand why, I've search a lot and can't get it to work.

Here is my code, in the beginning of the php page:

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "Formulaire_Ajout_Compte")) {

// reCAPTCHA
require_once('inc/recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "MY_PRIVATE_KEY";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                               $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                               $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                               $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

if (!$resp->is_valid) {
   die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
        "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
} else {

// if reCAPTCHA is OK... the end of my code then SQL injections
```

in my form, I have :

```
<?php
          require_once('inc/recaptchalib.php');
          $publickey = "MY_PUBLIC_KEY";
          echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
        ?>
```

the "lib" is at the right place and I don't understand why it doesn't work at all.

Comment: I've found other interesting things @ expert exchange but still not working

Comment: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/PHP/PHP_Databases/Q_24729733.html

Answer (score 0):

I have found my answer ... I found it in the logs of MAMP.
Permissions issues, I changed it to have it all on files and folders
and I think everything is ok.